# MFCで自動生成されるCViewのメンバ関数を呼ばないとどうなるか

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

MFCでプログラミングをしていますが、クラスウィザードでハンドラーを追加すると以下のようなコードが追加されると思います。

```
    void CSampleView::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
    {
      // TODO: ここにメッセージ ハンドラ コードを追加するか、既定の処理を呼び出します。
      CView::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
    }
```

例えばこれを

```
    void CSampleView::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
    {
      // TODO: ここにメッセージ ハンドラ コードを追加するか、既定の処理を呼び出します。
      return;
      CView::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
    }
```

などとした場合、何か不具合があるのでしょうか。これはTODOで書かれている「既定の処理」であり自分の処理をする場合、無視してもよいものでしょうか。
CViewのメンバ関数をF12でたどってもインラインのよくわからない記述しかなく、余計な関数であれば呼びたくないのですが。あまり経験がないのでよくわからないというところです。

---

コメントのMarkdownが機能しないので、ここに書いておきます。

```
void CSampleView::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)  
{  
  // TODO: ここにメッセージ ハンドラ コードを追加するか、既定の処理を呼び出します。  
  if(point.x>0)
  {
    m_moving_flag = true;    // m_moving_flag is member variable of View class
    CView::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
    return;
  }
  CView::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TODOコメントにある通り、特に処理を追加しないのであれば、

```
CView::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
```

を呼ばなければなりません。

MFCは基本的にはWindowsのGUIを構成するWindow Proceduresをラップしたものですので、Window Proceduresの仕様に従う必要があります。[Using Window Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633570(v=vs.85).aspx#designing_proc)で

> For messages that it does not process, the window procedure calls the **DefWindowProc** function.

と説明されているようにメッセージを処理しない場合は[DefWindowProc()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633572(v=vs.85).aspx)を呼び出す必要があります。MFCでは[CWnd::Default()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ww9f7hst.aspx)にてその処理が実装されており、また[CWnd::OnMouseMove()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/3158baat.aspx)は`CWnd::Default()`ひいては`DefWindowProc()`を呼び出すように設計されています。
ですので、特に処理を追加しないのであればこの呼び出しを省略することはできません。

---

> 「特に処理をする」というのは CDC* pDC = GetDC() を呼んで後にデバイスコンテキストを関係させるような処理なのでしょうか。

この点、あいまいでした。一概に回答できません。
Window Proceduresをラップしたものですので、`CView::OnMouseMove()`はそれに対応する[WM_MOUSEMOVE message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645616(v=vs.85).aspx)に説明されている処理を行う必要があります。といってもこの例に関していえば特にすべき処理は言及されていないため、処理したと考えてもいいのかもしれません。処理した場合は

> it should return zero.

を実現すればいいところですが…`CView::OnMouseMove()`ハンドラーは戻り値が`void`であり簡単にはいきませんので、やはり`CView::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point)`を呼ぶことでしょうか。

厳密な話をすると`wincore.cpp`に実装されている`CWnd::OnDndMsg()`は最初の行に

```
LRESULT lResult = 0;
```

とあり、その後、特に値を変更していないのでこの値が返されるようです。ここまで把握していれば`CView::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point)`を呼ばなくてもいいかもしれません。（私も回答するにあたって調べただけで普段は深く考えずに呼び出しています。）

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。「特に処理をしない」というのがよくわかってないのですが、

「特に処理をする」というのは

`CDC* pDC = GetDC()`

を呼んで後にデバイスコンテキストを関係させるような処理なのでしょうか。いずれにせよ省略せず呼べば楽そうですが。

以下は特に処理をしないので、`CView::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point)`は呼んでから返せばよいということしょうか。

（編注：ここに記載されていたコードは質問文に移動しました）

Comment: @Nick とりあえず上のコメントや自己回答に書かれていたコードを質問文に移動しました。[コメント欄で使えるMarkdownは制限されていて](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)、複数行のコードブロック、というか改行自体使えません。回答として書くのも適切ではないので、質問文に書いたうえでコメントで知らせる、という形をよく見かけます。

Comment: @unarist ありがとうござます。助かります。意外とコツがあるものなんですね。。

Comment: @sayuri 詳細に回答くださってありがとうございます。経験に基づくご回答で、とてもありがたいです。早期returnする場合は、ラップするのを追うのは大変なので、深く考えず呼ぶのが良いですね。